# Prevent JQUERY .load from cache

Tags: jquery, html, http

It seems that in IE9, using jquery .load will pull data from the browsers cache and so the 'real time' effect of AJAX loading content isnt working.  Is there any kind of switch to force jquery .load to get the data fresh?

Thansk!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The option to disable caching is available in jQuery if you are using the `$.ajax` low-level method.  This is not represented in the simplified signature for `load`.  You could mimic it instead, by ensuring that the URL is always unique.  You can put the current time in milliseconds on the end of the URL to achieve that, since that will practically always be unique:

```
url += '?_=' + Date.now();
```

(This presumes that `url` is a string containing the request URL and that it doesn't have any query parameters currently.)

Comment: Why not just `Date.now()` instead of `(new Date()).getTime()`?

Comment: @Théophile Because in 2011, when I wrote this, ES5 was still only moderately well supported! I'll change it for today's much better world.

Comment: What a joy to be in 2020. :)

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set the `cache` option to `false` which will cause jQuery to append a timestamp to the request URL under the hood:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "foo.html",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("#foo").html(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On the page content you try to load, make it to send header first so that request will not use cache...

For example, on the top of the code, add following lines

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//Other page contents that have to be loaded

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

```
elem.load(url, "f" + (new Date()).valueOf());
```

so that every request gets a new unique value appended to the query string