# Load select options from file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove select options from my html select field using a file on disk to store these options.

I got stuck trying to remove options from select. I use a jQuery function that sends a request to PHP what option to delete from the select list:

`$.post("buttons.php",{name: value}, function());`

And PHP part remove this line from the list:

```
$str = $_POST['name'];
$file = fopen("../list.csv", "rw");

while(! feof($file))
{
  $line = fgets($file);
  $pieces = explode(",", $line);
  if ($pieces[0]!=$str)
    file_put_contents('../tmp.csv', $line,FILE_APPEND); 
}

copy ("../tmp.csv","../list.csv");
fclose($file);
```

So far so good. Then I try to read the updated file with select options and change the option content:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open('GET', '../list.csv', false);  
client.send(null);

if (client.status === 200) {
  alert('response text = ' + client.responseText);
}

words = file_content.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     names = words[i].split(",");
       if (names[0]!=0)
          ddl.append("<option style='color:black' value='" + names[0] + "'>" + names[0] + "</option>");
}
```

The problem is that when I read `list.csv` file again in jQuery (after it was updated by PHP) to update select input I get the same `list.csv` file  content as before, but I see that the file content was changed (just open `list.csv` in text editor). It looks like the file content is stored somewhere and I get just a copy of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you were actually using jQuery for the Ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802463/prevent-jquery-load-from-cache

Comment: Look like I missed this post, though I looked carefully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User a random query string with your file

```
var rand = Math.random();
client.open('GET', '../list.csv?rand='+rand, false);
```

or use 
POST method to get file

Comment: Thank you, saqibahmad! Works perfectly!

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted answer so others with same issue can get it, i will be thank full.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, why not

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "../list.csv",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false, // this is the parm you want
    success: function(data) {
      var lines = data.split("\n"), options=[];
      $.each(lines,function(_,line) {
        var name = line.split(",")[0];
        if (name!=0) {
          options.push("<option style='color:black' value='" + name + "'>" + name + "</option>");
        }
      });
      if (options.length>0) ddl.append(options);
    }
});
```